# Return the index of clicked button?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton

I have got an array of 30 buttons []. I have a variable buttonClicked. When I press the button how can I get the index and store the index number in the buttonClicked?

Thanks :)

```
JButton [] buttons = new JButton[30]; 


        for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {       
            int btnNumber = (i > 10 && i <= 20) ? (31 - i) : i;

            System.out.printf("i = %d, btnNumber = %d%n", i, btnNumber);
            buttons[btnNumber - 1] = new JButton("label " + btnNumber);
            //buttons[btnNumber - 1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            buttons[btnNumber - 1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
            buttons[btnNumber - 1].setOpaque(true);
            buttons[btnNumber - 1].setBackground(Color.white);

            //Puts the player 1 piece on button 1,3,5,7,9 and player 2 piece on button 2,4,6,8,10 
            if ((btnNumber - 1) < 10) 
            { 
                if (((btnNumber - 1) % 2) == 0) 
                { 
                    buttons[btnNumber - 1].setIcon(piece1); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    buttons[btnNumber - 1].setIcon(piece2); 
                } 
            } 
            centerPanel.add(buttons[btnNumber - 1]); 
        }
```

//Below is what I am attempting to do, I know is not correct.

```
public void move()
{
Move = dice.getDiceResult();
int buttonClicked = 0;

if(playerOneTurn =true)
{
buttonclicked + diceResult();
}
```

//revised

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
Dice dice;
private boolean playerOneTurn = true;
private boolean playerTwoTurn = false;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    String num = e.getActionCommand();
    int index = Integer.parseInt(num);
    int move = dice.getDiceResult();
    int positionLanding = 0;

    if(playerOneTurn = true)
    {
        positionLanding = index + move;
        positionLanding.setIcon("piece1");//how can I set the image Icon to this position?
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Show us some code. We're not mind readers. Are you using [tag:swing]?

Comment: You can look at the Java keypress API at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) link

Comment: ButtonClickEvents does not work for this case? (Press one of these 30 buttons or press another button?)

Comment: @phantasmagoria press one of these 30 buttons. Check my code above

Answer (score 5):

1) [putClientProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29)

```
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("column", i);
buttons[i][j].putClientProperty("row", j);
buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
```

and [getClientProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getClientProperty%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
    System.out.println("clicked column " + btn.getClientProperty("column")
            + ", row " + btn.getClientProperty("row"));
}
```

2) [ActionCommand](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the button in `ActionEvent.getSource()`. To find the index it is just a matter of iterating through the array, looking for that particular button.

Answer (score 2):

The prettiest way is using Component.setName. Then you don't even need to maintain variables with your components - you can go straight off of the name

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the strategy suggested by aioobe, but here is another way.

```
buttons[btnNumber - 1] = new JButton("label " + btnNumber);
buttons[btnNumber - 1].setActionCommand("" + btnNumber);
// ...

// ...later.. in the actionPerformed() method
String num = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
int index = Integer.parseInt(num);
// ..proceed..
```

Comment: Please check the revised version. How can I set the imageIcon on the PositionLanding index? It is giving an int cannot be derefernced error.