# Creating form for CRUD dynamically at run time depending upon the table structure

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I am stuck at a problem and I have been googling around and read quite few resources and feel direction right now.

HERE is my problem.
I am working on an application which will act like CRUD application for a MySQL database with variable tables and structures, I cannot have fixed no. of tables and structures.

I am directionless at creating form for variable table structure. What i want to achieve is when a user selects the table name from combobox relevant no. of fields should be created after retrieving the table structure of that particular table.

Achievement so far:
-I have been able fetch structure/schema, data types, data of the table.
-Can write queries to create, update, delete the same.

can't succeed in:
-I want to create JTextField with unique object names of JTextField relevant to associated column name in the table.
-Column names are String type how can I covert them to Object of JTextField.

For example

```
String f1 = "fieldname_1";  // In reality these string values will be fetched from database resultset containing column names as identifier.
String f2 = "fieldname_2";  // In reality these string values will be fetched from database resultset containing column names as identifier.
JTextField f1 = new JTextField ();

or 

String[] f = {"fieldname_1", "fieldname_2"}; 
JTextField f[0] = new JTextField ();
```

but it gives error such as f1 is already defined

Note : I want to have input field names to be unique so that i will be easier to access there data after input.

Corrections to the question are welcome, If my approach to handle the problem is wrong give a brief idea/approach to pursue it in right direction.

Regards

Comment: `I want to create JTextField with unique object names of JTextField relevant to associated column name in the table` == [get/putClientProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10416286/714968) or [EventHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9007348/714968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create unique variable names based on the column name.

Instead you could create a `HashMap` to map the column name to the text field used in the form:

```
HashMap<String, JTextField> textFields = new HashMap<String, JTextField>();
```

Then you have a method that adds the text field to the form for each column name. Something like:

```
provide void addTextField(JPanel form, String columnName)
{
    Jlabel label = new JLabel( columnName );
    form.add( label );
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    form.add( textField );
    textFields.put(columnName, textField);
}
```

Of course you would need to modify for the proper layout you want to use.

Then when you want to access the text field for the given column you can use:

```
JTextField textField = textFields.get(columnName);
```